# Jmenu Accordion

Tags: java, user-interface, accordion, jmenu

I am trying to make a menu that can have subclasses (looking like a webshop for ex) with the purpose of filtering some things in the GUI.!

So when you click on a menu item for example, it opens its submenus that can also be selected and when you deselect the main menu item it closes up.

Something like:

```
Cars
  -bmw
  -vw
bikes
skateboards
```

Comment: please Accordion for Swing, SWT, GWT or e.i. ???

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a Tree?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html

You can easily extend this class to suit your needs, and I think it pretty much does what you want.

For more info you need to make your question clearer.